# Babel minify outputs double quotes instead of single quotes

Tags: babeljs, minify

Here is my babelrc

```
{
 "presets": ["es2015"],
 "env": {
   "production": {
     "presets": ["minify"],
     "comments": false
  }
 }
}
```

And I'm transpiling from command line

```
npx babel test.js --source-maps
```

and my minified output has double quotes, even though my source uses single quotes.  Could someone help point out how I could get minified output with single quotes?  Thank you.

Comment: The formatting of output code shouldn't be important in this case.

Comment: I see, it's just that a few days ago it was outputting single quotes, all of a sudden it's changed to double. So I was curious to see what controls this and based on my research I didn't see settings or parameters that control it. Like you suggested this isn't a big deal. Thanks.

Comment: I'd also like to know why this change happened

Comment: @RayFan just started to get this after upgrade to Babel 7, did you managed to figure this out?

Comment: @webdevbyjoss not yet :(

Comment: any updates about how to avoid this ?